# Can you notify @user who commented on another answer?

Tags: support, comments, notifications

Will notification of @user in comment to an answer actually notify user which was commenting on another answer of the same question? The user autocompleter doesn't autocomplete the name.

I think information on this is missing in [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/43020/166308).

Comment: Nope, you can't.

Comment: Too bad! Then I have to write another comment on that answer too! Too much clutter! This should be supported to reduce comment clutter!

Comment: It says _"Notifications apply to the author, users with active bounties, commenters (associated to current non-deleted comments), and editors of the question or answer that you are commenting on—users not in that list cannot be notified."_, so your question is already answered... it doesn't cross posts.

Comment: Hey this is not a duplicate, @benisuǝqbackwards and others! From the statement *"commenters (associated to current non-deleted comments)"* is not clear **which commenters** are meant - commenters of this post, of all post of this question, all commenters on the site??? *"associated to current non-deleted comments"* sounds bit like circular defintion.

Comment: Yes, you have to read the rest of the quotation: *"...of the question or answer that you are commenting on..."* Thus, you can only notify users who are participating in the same comment "thread" as you're posting your comment in.

Comment: @CodyGray, nope! As it is written now it looks as this quote is related only to *editors*! *""Notifications apply to the author, users with active bounties, commenters (associated to current non-deleted comments), and editors of the question or answer that you are commenting on—users not in that list cannot be notified."*

Comment: I don't know why you think that, that's not how English works. That phrase at the end of the list applies to each individual item in the comma-separated list. If you have an idea how it could be re-written to be clearer, you could always edit the answer. It is a community wiki.

Comment: @Cody You are right, but it could be understood in both ways. But I don't have an idea how to improve it without making the text significantly longer.

Answer (score 1):

> Notifications apply to the author, users with active bounties,
>   commenters (associated to current non-deleted comments), and editors
>   of the question or answer that you are commenting on—users not in that
>   list cannot be notified. You can also notify a ♦ moderator who closed
>   the question. The question and answers are all considered
>   independently. For example, if Alice was the author of, commented on,
>   or edited the question or her answer, then you cannot notify her by
>   commenting on Bob's answer (unless Alice also participated in that
>   answer), and vice versa.

Comment: ... or who have done [many other things](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/43020/166308)...

Comment: @Tomas: So you already know the answer, why did you ask?

Comment: Because it is not clear from the answer, see my comment above!